# How can I display data from Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the application, you can add your bank to the Firebase database. When you click on the "Add Bank" button, the bank is saved to the database. I need to display cards with added banks on the screen. How can i do this? Now I am reading data from the database and it comes in the form of an object:

[image]

Code for read data:

```js
const getBanksFunc = () => {
  const bankRef = ref(database, "banks/");
  onValue(bankRef, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase's documentation covers this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

```
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";

const db = getDatabase();
const starCountRef = ref(db, 'posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  updateStarCount(postElement, data);
});
```

In your case, a for .. in loop could work:

```
for(let key in data) {
    const { bankName, interestRate, loanTerm, maximumLoan, minimumDownPayment } = data[key];
    ... do whatever you need
}
```